# Load Kendo TabStrip with available content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have three tabs and I would like to populate those tabs with section contents that is already present on the page:

```
<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466479" name="world1">
<p>Hello World1</p>
</section>

<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466477" name="world2">
<p>Hello World2</p>
</section>

<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466478" name="world3">
<p>Hello World3</p>
</section>
```

My TabStrip:

```
<div id="tabstrip">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="k-state-active">
                                    World1
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    World2                                    </li>
                                <li>
                                    Wordl3
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
                        animation:  {
                            open: {
                                effects: "fadeIn"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

How can I use Kendo TabStrip code to use my custom sections in those tabs? Kindly let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

here is a dojo with a working example. [Tab strip with sections.](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwEki)

You will notice that all I have done is wrap you `sections` with a div.

the tab strip expects to see a `div` within the content collection as the child element i.e. the content.

hopefully this answers your question. If you need any further details let me know.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the dojo. It is not the most elegant way of doing it but it will work without you changing your DOM to much.

[updated dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwEki/5)

**UPDATE 2**
[updated dojo 2](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwEki/7)

Comment: Your dojo doesn't really work properly as it doesn't have the wrapped divs. My sections are already available on the page. I do not have the option of creating those sections myself. I can just move the sections and I would like to move them into divs just under the unordered list. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: I do understand that the sections wrapped in divs need to be placed below the unordered list but because they are already available elsewhere, I would like to use them as my contents for the tabs. Updated your dojo to explain how the DOM looks and how I want it: http://dojo.telerik.com/iwEki/2

Comment: Do you want this content to appear under the tabs or just where they are located in your DOM?

Comment: updated answer with new dojo. hopefully this works for you http://dojo.telerik.com/iwEki/5

Comment: It partially does work but I had something similar to this working before. The main reason why I am trying to make this work is because there are some animation div's that don't get cloned across for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88597/discussion-between-the-newbie-and-david-shorthose).